# No space left on device session_files_driver.php CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use CodeIngniter 3, php 7.4 on my cpanel website. But sometimes there is an tmp folder full. I wonder why this happend.

The error message is like this:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: fwrite(): write of 59 bytes failed with errno=28 No space left on device

Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php

Line Number: 265

Backtrace:

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: session_write_close(): Failed to write session data using user defined save handler. (session.save_path: /tmp)

Filename: Unknown

Line Number: 0

Backtrace:
```

And if i run `df` in terminal, the result is like this:

```
Filesystem               1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                  32602664         0  32602664   0% /dev
tmpfs                     32613448         0  32613448   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     32613448   3222048  29391400  10% /run
tmpfs                     32613448         0  32613448   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb2                451321540  24802612 426518928   6% /
/dev/sda1                   484004    212704    271300  44% /boot
/dev/mapper/centos-home 1084803556 399075828 685727728  37% /data
/dev/loop0                 3997376   3787664         0 100% /tmp <- FULL
```

Is there any suggestion for this problem? Thanks before.

Comment: Delete some stuff from /tmp? Make /tmp bigger? Don't store your sessions in /tmp?

Comment: How to not store session in /tmp? Because i dont have a permission to delete /tmp or make it bigger

Comment: Read the Code Igniter docs to learn how to specify a custom location to store your sessions.